# Spliting a date from time using parseInt in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to split a data and time from a var in javascript.

var str = "2014-12-11t0550";

i want to split "2014-12-11"     and "t0550"

How do i do this i am not able to understand ...?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Splitting and Parsing are two very different things!

Comment: yes i did at this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp but couldn't get the desired ans.

Comment: There are many different ways you can parse this

Comment: i know this in java . but i am new to javascript . i know it could be same in all languages but i want the desired result can you please answer it how do i do this . i'll be thankful to you .

Comment: The way you do this in `Java` is syntaxually the same way in `Javascript`.

Comment: Can do this Drew Kennedy . as i am not able to get desired one . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split()` method would give you the desired results:

```
var str = "2014-12-11t0550";
var split = str.split("t");

var date = split[0];
var time = split[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

So the simplest method is probably to just split the string. ..

```
var str = "2014-12-11t0550";
var parts = str.split('t');
// parts[0] === "2014-12-11"
// parts[1] === "0550"
```

You can then `parseInt(parts[1])` if you like.

Comment: it not working paul. when i am going to get the parts[0] result. it shows 2014 only but i want the whole 2014-12-11 .

Comment: @Travelers are you splitting by `t`? Because it sounds as though you are splitting by `-`.

Comment: @JonathanGray, yeah looks like we answered within minutes of each other.  Great minds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "2014-12-11t0550";
var splitsring = str.exec((/(\d+\-\d+\-\d+)(t.*)/)
var fsring = splitsring[1]
var secondstring = splitsring[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not split anything using the [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function.

> The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix or base.

Looking at the input text, it seems like you want to split the string at the occurrence of the  character `t`. For this you can use the [`split()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and specify `t` as the delimiter:

```
var str = "2014-12-11t0550";
var split_arr = str.split( "t" );
```

What you are left with in the `split_arr` variable is the following structure:

```
["2014-12-11", "0550"]
```

Note that the delimiter `t` has been removed.

Reference - [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `substr` or `substring` but if you want to use `split` this is what you would get:

```
var strarr = "2014-12-11t0550".split("t");
// strarr[0] === "2014-12-11"
// strarr[1] === "0550"
```